# ShareActionProvider with one icon - looking as simple actionitem

Tags: android, android-actionbar, shareactionprovider

I want to dislay `ShareActionProvider` on `ActionBar`, but with custom look&feel. Only one simple share icon without borders and without most used app icon on the right. But providing popup menu with most used applications. Is there a simple way to do it without implementing own `ShareActionProvider`?