# Drop down menu with strings + pictures

Tags: android, drop-down-menu

I am using a dropdown menu and i put inside it only a strings but i want when i click on the action bar on the drop down menu widget that when the list of choices drops  i will see not only strings but pictures for each choice , i tried to look it up but i dont find something relevant on how doing it.
Example for what i am talking about is this 
http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-mVQddiSMz0I/TzL2y2Ny5uI/AAAAAAAABKo/ikNPtWiPu4w/s1600/Screenshot_2012-02-08-14-01-21.png So can you give me an example and explanation on doing it please?
Thanks

Comment: Look at answers that may be help you

Answer (score 0):

Use ActionBar, see this documentation:

[Adding an Action Provider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionProvider)

The ShareActionProvider is an extension of ActionProvider that facilitates a “share" action by showing a list of available share targets from the action bar.

[image]

With ActionProvider you can add menu and you can create custom your menu item.
Here have how to create menu item xml documentation:

[Menu Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html)

And see example: [menu with photo](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2012/08/share-with-photo-using.html)

And here have how to add icon stream to inten for ShareIntent see:
[ShareActionProvider with one icon - looking as simple actionitem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14745740/shareactionprovider-with-one-icon-looking-as-simple-actionitem)

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot is of a `ListPopupWindow` as used by a `ShareActionProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to use a `ShareActionProvider`, but just a `Spinner` with pictures and text, you can add submenus to your actionbar as shown here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8312985/626787

Or you can add a `Spinner` as an action and fill it with a `CustomAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

As @mbarrben said you do not need `ShareActionProvider`. You only need a Spinner and implemet a CustomAdapter. Below you can see a simple example([Full example here](http://github.com/androidzin/android-examples)

On your activity you should have that:

```
public class SpinnerIconActivity extends SherlockActivity implements OnNavigationListener{

private SpinnerAdapter mSpinnerAdapter;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_spinner_icon);

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);


    List<SpinnerRow> options = new ArrayList<SpinnerRow>();
    options.add(new SpinnerRow("Droid 1", R.drawable.android01));
    options.add(new SpinnerRow("Droid 2", R.drawable.android02));
    options.add(new SpinnerRow("Droid 3", R.drawable.android03));
    mSpinnerAdapter  = new MySpinnerAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            R.layout.spinner_row, R.id.text, options);

        actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(mSpinnerAdapter, this);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(int itemPosition, long itemId) {
    return false;
   }

}
```

**The most important thing is write your custom adapter.** I choosed use ArrayAdapter because using it **i just need to override one method**.

The approach to write a customAdapter is the same to create customizable ListView with one basic difference, **instead to override the getView method, you must override getDropDownView**.

So, below is my example:

```
public class MySpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<SpinnerRow> {

private List<SpinnerRow> rows;
private int resource;

public MySpinnerAdapter(Context context, int resource,
        int textViewResourceId, List<SpinnerRow> objects) {
    super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, objects);
    rows = objects;
    this.resource = resource;
}

static class ViewHolder {

    TextView text;
    ImageView icon;
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder  holder = new ViewHolder();
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(resource,
                parent, false);

        holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    SpinnerRow currentRow = rows.get(position);
    holder.text.setText(currentRow.toString());
    holder.icon.setImageDrawable(
            getContext().getResources().getDrawable(currentRow.getIconResourceId()));


    return convertView;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer the link which is provided by google =>
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionProvider